# how to round off digit to 7 decimal place in java

Tags: java, math

I am making a java program in which i have to round off the double digit to seven place but I don't know how to do it.
     `like 6.6666667e-10 to 0.0000001`

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#######"); df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

Comment: @i-bob it's giving 0 for above answer but i need 0.0000001

Answer (score 1):

The reason it return 0 is because the number example is too small. it can't be rounded to 7 digits after decimal point because the first nonzero digit in it's full decimal representation is after the 7th digit.

However, for slightly bigger numbers, this code should do the trick:

```
double a = 6.66666667E-10;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#######");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(df.format(a));
```

Comment: nope it's giving 0 again

Comment: Like I said, the number in the example is too small.
Try a bigger number or try with more than 7 digits.